# Powerapps assigning data from one collection to another in a loop

Tags: powerapps

I have a problem with the function below:

```
ClearCollect( 

    TimeSpentData; 

    ForAll( 

        WebData; 

        Collect( 

            WebDataWithTimeSpent; 

            { 

                UserID: WebData[@UserID]; 

                Page: WebData[@Page]; 

                SessionID: WebData[@SessionID]; 

                Timestamp: WebData[@Timestamp]; 

                TimeSpent: If( 

                    IsBlank(LookUp( 

                        WebData; 

                        UserID = WebData[@UserID] && SessionID = WebData[@SessionID] && Timestamp > WebData[@Timestamp] 

                    )); 

                    Blank(); 

                    DateDiff( 

                        WebData[@Timestamp]; 

                        LookUp( 

                            WebData; 

                            UserID = WebData[@UserID] && SessionID = WebData[@SessionID] && Timestamp > WebData[@Timestamp]; 

                            Timestamp 

                        ); 

                        TimeUnit.Minutes 

                    ) 

                ) 

            } 

        ) 

    ) 

);; 

 

ClearCollect( 

    AvgTimeSpentData; 

    AddColumns( 

        GroupBy(TimeSpentData; "Page"; "AllRows"); 

        "AvgTimeSpent"; Average(AllRows; TimeSpent) 

    ) 

);;
```

I want to calculate the average time spent on a website using data from the webdata collection. Every time nothing is written to the WebDataWithTimeSpent collection to TimeSpent. It seems to me that the if condition is incorrect, I have no idea how to fix it

This is my test webData collection:

```
ClearCollect(
    WebData;
    {
        UserID: "User1";
        Page: "Homepage";
        Timestamp: DateTimeValue("2023-01-01T10:00:00Z");
        SessionID: "Session1"
    };
    {
        UserID: "User1";
        Page: "Page2";
        Timestamp: DateTimeValue("2023-01-01T10:05:00Z");
        SessionID: "Session1"
    };
    {
        UserID: "User1";
        Page: "Page3";
        Timestamp: DateTimeValue("2023-01-01T10:10:00Z");
        SessionID: "Session1"
    };
    {
        UserID: "User2";
        Page: "Homepage";
        Timestamp: DateTimeValue("2023-01-01T10:15:00Z");
        SessionID: "Session2"
    };
    {
        UserID: "User2";
        Page: "Homepage";
        Timestamp: DateTimeValue("2023-01-01T10:20:00Z");
        SessionID: "Session2"
    } );;
```

could anyone help?